# TLS1.2 TLS hello rejected with a TCP reset

Tags: sha256, tls1.2

We recently faced an issue when one of our clients got a TCP reset from our server every time they sent a TLS1.2 Client Hello.
The SChannel error logged was :
"An TLS1.2 connection request was recieved from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed."
Our server has SHA256 certificate.

Comment: "When failing clients offers TLS1.2 without signature_algorithms extension, SChannel server assumes that this client only understands SHA1. 
If the SChannel server only has a SHA256 certificate, it will terminate the handshake. " When we asked the client to add signature_algorithms extension to their client hello this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

"When failing clients offers TLS1.2 without signature_algorithms extension, SChannel server assumes that this client only understands SHA1. If the SChannel server only has a SHA256 certificate, it will terminate the handshake. " When we asked the client to add signature_algorithms extension to their client hello this issue was resolved.